# Is it possible to modify the animal tags (EM4305) with any module that works with Arduino? 134,2Khz

Tags: rfid

i have a lot of tags (Animal tags rounded yellow) EM4305, this have 15 spaces of memory and i need change ID writed, currently i'm using this [module](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiU6cankO_nAhVOBpEKHdvEAl8YABAFGgJjZQ&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAESQOD2sm1tQSQkF0ISO-Jwj_Pw5zEjqQsV_eqxy0TJlpChx1eiepIa0LVX0Sj-UGt-MPNY_HI21kD7GGHT2ejgCZs&sig=AOD64_0LlaeH46FM4xIIfU2newmTSJIpTg&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwikyMCnkO_nAhX1H7kGHfQtCvkQ9aACegQICxA6&adurl=) but it did not can possible write on tag, exist a similar function to Write() from EEPROM, i see that already exist external writers to EM4305, but, is only external?

Comment: Why are you linking to a google ad? Please provide a direct link to the module. And what are you talking about EEPROM? I really don't understand, what you mean there and with the "external"

Comment: What are the tags used for? In some places ID tags are used to track animals through the supply change and there could be legal consequences to changing the IDs.